# javascript ordering elements in array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have the following array:

```
    [{"cod_nivel":"INC2","cod_modelo":"D"},
    {"cod_nivel":"INC2","cod_modelo":"B"},    
    {"cod_nivel":"PRIM","cod_modelo":"B"},    
    {"cod_nivel":"PRIM","cod_modelo":"D"},
    {"cod_nivel":"PRIM2","cod_modelo":"B"},    
    {"cod_nivel":"PRIM2","cod_modelo":"D"},    
    {"cod_nivel":"PRIM2","cod_modelo":"A"}]
```

I need to order this array of objects by "cod_modelo" ascending grouped by "cod_nivel". So the result should be:

```
    [{"cod_nivel":"INC2","cod_modelo":"B"},
    {"cod_nivel":"INC2","cod_modelo":"D"},    
    {"cod_nivel":"PRIM","cod_modelo":"B"},    
    {"cod_nivel":"PRIM","cod_modelo":"D"},
    {"cod_nivel":"PRIM2","cod_modelo":"A"},    
    {"cod_nivel":"PRIM2","cod_modelo":"B"},    
    {"cod_nivel":"PRIM2","cod_modelo":"D"}]
```

My attemp:

```
var array = [{"cod_nivel":"INC2","cod_modelo":"D"},
        {"cod_nivel":"INC2","cod_modelo":"B"},    
        {"cod_nivel":"PRIM","cod_modelo":"B"},    
        {"cod_nivel":"PRIM","cod_modelo":"D"},
        {"cod_nivel":"PRIM2","cod_modelo":"B"},    
        {"cod_nivel":"PRIM2","cod_modelo":"D"},    
        {"cod_nivel":"PRIM2","cod_modelo":"A"}];
  var groups = {}; // I know i need some temp object to store the current level that is being ordered..
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
         groups.push(array[i]);
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The **[sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)** method will do the work for you.

This code sorts the array, first by `cod_nivel`, then by `cod_modelo`.

The conditional operator:

```
condition ? expr1 : expr2
```

… is used to compare the array's elements by key.  (The conditional operator is often called the "ternary operator" because it's the only JavaScript operator that takes three operands.)

```js
var arr= [{"cod_nivel":"INC2","cod_modelo":"D"},
          {"cod_nivel":"INC2","cod_modelo":"B"},    
          {"cod_nivel":"PRIM","cod_modelo":"B"},    
          {"cod_nivel":"PRIM","cod_modelo":"D"},
          {"cod_nivel":"PRIM2","cod_modelo":"B"},    
          {"cod_nivel":"PRIM2","cod_modelo":"D"},    
          {"cod_nivel":"PRIM2","cod_modelo":"A"}
         ];

var sorted= arr.sort(function(a, b) {
  return a.cod_nivel  > b.cod_nivel  ? 1 :
         a.cod_nivel  < b.cod_nivel  ? -1 :
         a.cod_modelo > b.cod_modelo ? 1 :
         a.cod_modelo < b.cod_modelo ? -1 :
         0;
});

document.body.innerHTML= JSON.stringify(sorted).replace(/},/g,'},<br>');
```

Comment: methinks you need check `cod_nivel` first

Comment: yes, but it is not grouped by cod_nivel after ordering it by cod_modelo. It needs to be grouped by cod_nivel (they need to be one after another the objects of same cod_nivel)

Comment: Sorry, I interpreted the question as needing to be sorted by `cod_modelo` first.  I'll update.

Answer (score 2):

```
var array = [{"cod_nivel":"INC2","cod_modelo":"D"},
    {"cod_nivel":"INC2","cod_modelo":"B"},    
    {"cod_nivel":"PRIM","cod_modelo":"B"},    
    {"cod_nivel":"PRIM","cod_modelo":"D"},
    {"cod_nivel":"PRIM2","cod_modelo":"B"},    
    {"cod_nivel":"PRIM2","cod_modelo":"D"},    
    {"cod_nivel":"PRIM2","cod_modelo":"A"}];


var sortedArray = array.sort(function(a,b) {
            return (a["cod_nivel"] > b["cod_nivel"]) ? 1 : -1;
    }).sort(function(a,b) {
            if(a["cod_nivel"] == b["cod_nivel"])
                return (a["cod_modelo"] > b["cod_modelo"]) ? 1 : -1;
            else 
                return 0;
    });
console.log(sortedArray);
```

> **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gxcj1c4q/)**

Answer (score 0):

If there is no restriction of using a external javascript library, you can use **Underscore js**, this library is specifically designed for working with javascript objects and collections. you can take the following example for the solution

```
var stooges = [{name: 'moe', age: 40}, {name: 'larry', age: 50}, {name: 'curly', age: 60}];

var sort = _.sortBy(stooges, 'name');
```

hope it helps ....